# Accessing variables, named with variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, for-loop, naming

I am very new to programming and I got a job from school to do a "forecast" weather map from random generated numbers.

I already got 7 different arrays for every day (day1 -> day7) and all the code afterwards to check the required stuff and create the weather map.

Now I have the problem that I'd like to go through all the 7 arrays in 1 for-loop. I asked a friend and I think it's a very tiny thing missing / done wrong...

As I already got all the code afterwards (currently hardcoded for 1 day) I'd be pleased if you could provide me a solution for my (I guess crappy) way, not a totally different way eventhough it's most likely much more efficent what so ever.

I tried it like this:

```
for($daynr = 1; $daynr < 8; $daynr++){
    $dayZ = 'day'.$daynr;
    print_r($$dayZ);
    ...
```

This works like a charm and gives out array 1-7. But when I try to access a part of dayZ I get stuck:

`echo $$dayZ[0][0]`

Gives out:

> Notice:  Undefined variable:  in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php
>   on line 139

As many stuff later like `$temp = explode('/',$$dayZ[$region_nr][3])...` need to access the day-array it would be cool to have a solution for that.

Btw, something like `echo $day1[0][0]` works without problems.

Any help very appreciated, thanks in advance

Best regards

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
${$dayZ}[0][0]
```

Keep in mind that this kind of variable format does NOT improve readability or good code.

Comment: says Notice:  Undefined variable: d in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 130   -- dunno where this "d" is comming from :/

Comment: ${$dayZ}[0][0]    --   got it!!! Thanks :) you're the best!   - I'll accept answer asap

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner solution would be to place the days in another array. So instead of `$day1`, `$day2` etc you have an array $days containing your arrays for each day.

```
$days[0][0][0] // monday
$days[1][0][0] // tuesday
// ...
```

Comment: can you tell me how i'd put my array in this array? I can't do it with my array_push :(